# Stop and Start AWS Elastic Beanstalk which is running php on EC2 and mysql RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS free tier, and running Elastic Beanstalk which is running EC2 and RDS, and I am looking for a way to stop and start the environment only when needed should i stop EC2 and RDS individually from the dashboard or what would be a good way of doing it?

One of the post i found was [When I stop and start an ec2 cents os instance , what data do I loose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950080/when-i-stop-and-start-an-ec2-cents-os-instance-what-data-do-i-loose) and it says data will not be lost but **how do I stop and start the EBS when needed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Beanstalk and try to stop particular EC2 instance from EC2 console than Beanstalk will bring it back automatically. If you want to stop whole EBS environment than you can use Terminate option that will terminate it, obviously. You will be able to bring it back for 40 days and after that it will be lost. Remember that you will see terminated environment for ~1h in the EBS console and after that time you will be able to bring it back only using `eb` tool so remember to write down your environment's ID so you can restore it later with `$ eb restore ENV_ID`

Comment: I had tried closing EC2, as you said, EBS brings it back.. If I terminate EBS and to bring it back after few days, I would have to use  Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface, right?

Comment: Exactly. If you terminate the instance from EC2 console, Beanstalk will see it as defunct and will automatically bring back another one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the EC2 instance is concerned, if you have a load-balanced, auto-scaling setup, then you can use the scheduled autoscaling feature to shrink your desired number of instances to zero on whatever schedule you like. To do this, go to the capacity section of the environment dashboard in the console, and scroll to the bottom ("[Time-based Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-scheduledactions.html)"). Here you can enter two cron expressions, one for scale out and one for scale in, for a recurring pattern which will shut down the EC2 instance when you like.

The RDS instance is a bit trickier. You could write a lambda function that would take a snapshot, shut it down, and later restore the snapshot to a new instance, scheduled using a cron expression or similar in [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). A similar approach could work for the EC2 instance and its EBS volume.